# Conditions for two critical points?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For $f(x) = ax^3 - bx$, where $a,b ≠ 0$, what are the conditions for the values of $a$ and $b$ such that $f(x)$ has two critical points.

$f'(x) = 3ax^2 - b = 0$. Not sure how to solve from here.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, the derivative of the function must have two roots (when it is equal to zero).  You have calculated the derivative, and now what is left is to find values of $a$ and $b$ such that the discriminant of $3ax^2 - b =0$ is strictly positive.  In your case, it must hold that

$$Disc. = 12ab >0,$$

It is easy to see that both $a$ and $b$ must be either strictly positive or strictly negative.

Comment: You mean discriminant.

Comment: Simplified to $a \cdot b > 0$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom. Yep, discriminant. Thanks - corrected

Comment: It's allright, never mind.